# Why does this comparison method violate its general contract?

Tags: java, exception, compare

I am using a special comparator to sort a list of pairs according to the second part of the pair:

```
Collections.sort(ans, new Comparator<Pair<Component, Double>>()
    {
      public int compare(Pair<Component, Double> l, Pair<Component, Double> r)
      {
        if (r.second - l.second < 0) return  -1;
        else if(r.second==l.second) return 0;
        else return 1;
      }
    });
```

The compare method seems to be both transitive (a < b < c => a < c) and each component
is equal to itself. What could cause the exception?

Comment: possible overflow in `r.second - l.second < 0`

Comment: Keep to the best practice and always use `Double.compare(double,double)` (and equivalents for all other primitive types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are edge cases you haven't considered—and shouldn't, because the JDK already provides a fully compliant method, which I present here for completeness::

```
public static int compare(double d1, double d2) {
    if (d1 < d2)
        return -1;           // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is smaller
    if (d1 > d2)
        return 1;            // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is larger

    // Cannot use doubleToRawLongBits because of possibility of NaNs.
    long thisBits    = Double.doubleToLongBits(d1);
    long anotherBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(d2);

    return (thisBits == anotherBits ?  0 : // Values are equal
            (thisBits < anotherBits ? -1 : // (-0.0, 0.0) or (!NaN, NaN)
             1));                          // (0.0, -0.0) or (NaN, !NaN)
}
```

Comment: +1 So to complete the answer, Marko is suggesting you just do `return Double.compare(l.second, r.second);` instead of the code you already have.